# FileWriter not writing?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I have this snippet of code:

```
        try {
            f1 = new File("sink.txt");
            f1.createNewFile();
            fw = new FileWriter(f1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ... code ...
        System.out.println(sequence);
        System.out.println(mySink.indexOf(sequence));
        String result = "";
        int firstIndex = mySink.indexOf(sequence);
        if (firstIndex >= 0) {
            System.out.println(true);
            int secondIndex = mySink.indexOf(sequence, firstIndex + sequence.length());
            if (secondIndex >= 0) {
                System.out.println(true);
                result = mySink.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex + sequence.length());
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
        try { // Write it to file
            fw.write(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("done");
```

When I ranit, it printed the string `sequence` and the index of it inside `mySink`. Then it goes inside the if statements and printed out the two `true` and printed out `result` so I know `result` was initialized successfully. But when I look into the file `sink.txt`, I see that it's blank. Why is it behaving this way? Did I miss something in my code? It was working before and I added some more code and it does this. I never touch the `FileWriter` or the `File` during the execution of the program. Thanks in advance!

This is my output if you want to see:

```
[93, 73, 74, 81, 89, 70, 50, 80, 51, 83, 62, 13, 50, 0, 40, 98, 48, 43, 47, 89]
2000466
true
true
[93, 73, 74, 81, 89, 70, 50, 80, 51, 83, 62, 13, 50, 0, 40, 98, 48, 43, 47, 89]
[93, 73, 74, 81, 89, 70, 50, 80, 51, 83, 62, 13, 50, 0, 40, 59, 48, 43, 47, 89]
[93, 73, 74, 81, 89, 70, 50, 80, 51, 83, 62, 13, 50, 0, 81, 59, 48, 43, 47, 89]
[93, 73, 74, 81, 89, 70, 50, 80, 51, 83, 62, 13, 50, 0, 81, 98, 48, 43, 47, 89]
[93, 73, 74, 81, 89, 70, 50, 80, 51, 83, 62, 13, 50, 0, 40, 98, 48, 43, 47, 89]
done
```

Comment: You aren't closing your `FileWriter`; `fw.close()`

Comment: Followup: Use try-with-resources when you open the file, and it will always be closed correctly.

Comment: Remove your try-catch blocks. Catching an exception and ignoring it, i.e. allow following code to continue executing, will just cause cascade failure. Example: If file cannot be create/replaced, an `IOException` will occur and `fw` will never be assigned. `fw.write(result)` will then fail with a `NullPointerException`. The error will be so misleading as to the cause.

Comment: Why catch `FileNotFoundException`? Neither `createNewFile()` nor `new FileWriter()` can throw it. --- Also, get rid of `createNewFile()`. It's not doing anything, since `new FileWriter()` will create or replace the file anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you are not closing (or flushing) your `FileWriter`.  That means that you application will exit with unwritten data still sitting in the file buffers.

There are a number of other mistakes in your code.  Starting from the top:

```
    try {
        f1 = new File("sink.txt");
        f1.createNewFile();
        fw = new FileWriter(f1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

1. The `createNewFile` call is redundant.  The following `new FileWriter` will create the file.
2. You are catching exceptions and continuing as if nothing has happened.  You >>cannot<< continue from those exceptions.  The rest of your code can only work properly if you succeeded in opening the file.
3. You don't need to catch `FileNotFoundException` unless you intend to handle it differently.  Catching `IOException` is sufficient, because it is a superclass of the former.
4. At this point, you *should* be using try-with-resources:

   ```
   f1 = new File("sink.txt");
   try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1)) {

      // compute stuff

      // write stuff to file

   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       // This is ugly for a real app.  However, an IOException that
       // is not a FileNotFoundException is "unexpected" at this point
       // and providing a user-friendly explanation would be tricky. 
       ex.printStackTrace();  
   }
   ```

   The try-with-resources will cause `fw` to be closed automatically when the block exits.  Closing the writer will first flush it.